# how to print the Object parameter in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I am new to log4j2. Here is the Scenario
I am tracing it as follows

```
log.trace("some message",object);
```

Now i would like to print the Object using the Console appender. My appender looks like this.

```
<Console name="Console">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</Console>
```

but right now it prints only.

```
"16:40:30.300 [main] TRACE com.xxx.skip.webservice.RunService - test"
```

But if "Object" is of instance Throwable it works fine but not for any other object.
Please point me right direction.

**Update**

Seems like it is not possible to custom log the object to a different field from the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to print your object as part of your log message? Then just do this:

```
log.trace("some message {}", object);
```

This is actually the same as:

```
log.trace("some message " + object);
```

But it's better because the `String` concatenation only happens if the level used (trace in this case) is enabled (lazy evaluation).

Comment: I have jdbc appender and i wanted the object in a different column instead of part of the message. So i though i could pass it in the second parameter because it accepts Object as input and also i read in apache site that it uses toString implementation to convert to String. In this case i have implemented the serializable interface for the Class.

Comment: Log4j gives you a few choices. You can use the ethos shown above off your object doesn't implement a nice toString method you can create your own Message implementation that formats the object and do logger.trace(new MyObjectMessage(object));

Comment: @SabareeshKkanan The method that accepts an `Object` as a second parameter does so to avoid superfluous object creation when the logger is disabled for some specific level, just as I wrote in my answer. You should read the [Javadoc](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#trace%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object%29). The [`PatternLayout`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) doesn't provide you an option to add a new column to represent an object. All you can do is to add your object to your message.

Comment: This answer only applies if using slf4j in addition to log4j?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 is a logging solution. Logging solutions write text messages to appenders -- file, standard out, a network location etc. It doesn't make sense to log an object. If you you really are sure that this is what you want to do, then add a meaningful `toString` to your object and log that.

```
log.trace("some message", object.toString());
```

If you are trying to **serialize** your object, you should take a different approach, as Log4j2 is not the right tool for this.

Comment: He missed the `{}` in the message `String`.